# Type narrowing incorrectly assumes callback can't run

Tags: typescript

Here's ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwgHwmgrsMBALx6HADcAUANoQCMEAugHQBmA9kgKICGAYwAWAChEBKUgD4IAb2oRopCACIhIIpxU0AvuJop2EEVFIkyBIpPmKwQpJwDueEM55IHSESvxokIQSE%20ACNQFX1qHWoBTjR4TlBWYE4MEySQTDt9IA)) some TypeScript:

```js
let x: string | null = null;
[ 1 ].forEach(() => {
  x = "hello";
});
if (x === null) {
  throw new Error("unreachable");
}
console.log(x.length);
```

On the `if` line, TS thinks `x` has type null. This means that by the last line, `x` has type never, and you get a type error.

Now, I know TS is conservative about code in closures. It can't assume that they will run and narrow types further or whatever. The thing that surprises me here is that TS seems to assume the code in the closure WON'T run, and `x` will necessarily be unchanged by the map operation. This isn't conservative behavior at all. It seems bug-level mistaken to me.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a good reason my desired behavior (assume that any closure passed into a function might be executed) isn't implemented in TypeScript?
2. Is there some pattern I should use to get around this trouble?

Naturally, in my code I'm not just looping over `[ 1 ]`; there's some kinda walker running in there.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts!

(For the record: this is all TypeScript 5.3.2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known issue and is tracked by [#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) & [11498](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11498).

Basically, TS has no way to know that `forEach` will be run instantly. It assumes that it is not ran. So the type is `null` from inference.

Comment: To clarify, I don't think TS needs to assume the closure WILL run. That would be tricky to pull off – TS would need to understand the semantics of functions you're handing the closure to. But I think it's strange that TS assumes the closure WON'T run. Why can't it do the same thing it would do if you put the code into an indeterminate `if` body?

Comment: That being said, I think you're right that https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998 is about this. I'm basically asking for "Pessimistic" behavior, and that issue tracks problems with it. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

@Matthieu Riegler answers your first question well. As for your second question:

> Is there some pattern I should use to get around this trouble?

In your example, you can replace `forEach` with `for...of`:

```
let x: string | null = null;
for (const _ of [1]) {
  x = "hello";
}
if (x === null) {
  throw new Error("unreachable");
}
console.log(x.length);
```

In the more general case, you can prevent `x` from being narrowed upon assignment by using `as`:

```
let x = null as string | null;
```